# IOS stringWithContentsOfURL returning null

Tags: ios, null, webkit

Heres a section of code that I have:

```
NSString * escAddress = [fromLocation stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //1
NSString * request = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=%@", escAddress]; //2
NSLog(@"%@", request); //3
NSString * result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:request] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil]; //4
NSLog(@"%@", result); //5
```

Output on line 3 is correct. It will read:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=stack%20overflow%20.%20com
```

if the string in escAddress is "stack overflow . com".

The problem seems to be in line 4. I'm not sure why but it keeps returning null. I can copy and paste the URL from the output on line 3, paste it into my browser, and I get the relevant information that I need. So why is it not putting it into the string? I have used this method before, now that I have updated to Xcode 6 it stopped.

Comment: Use the `error` parameter to see what the issue is.

Comment: `NSError *error = nil; NSString * result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:request] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]; //4`

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x7fa491ce1e70 {NSURL=http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=63123}

Comment: BTW - Why are you passing "stack overflow . com" as an address for a map?

Comment: Interestingly for me it works, I get: `{ "results" : [], "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS" }`

Comment: It's an example used here because I'm on stackoverflow.com. I didn't think it was relevant to put an actual address on there. The actual encoding is working is all I was demonstrating. I am obviously using real address searches when running the program.

Comment: Could this be something other than the program then? Firewall or something?

Comment: Turns out that it was not the program, or a firewall. It was Xcode or the simulator. Quit both, re-opened. Worked fine after. Since it started only after updating to Xcode 6, I figured something had changed. Oh well. Not sure why that would happen. Its working though.

Answer (score 0):

If the address is malformed the service returns: "NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=262", etc.. If it is a correct **street** address, not a domain address, it works. I looked up my street address, replacing all spaces with `%20` and it worked. If I failed to replace a space I got the error code 262.

By street address I mean (example):
`100 Main Street, Anytown, ST ZCode`
encoded to:
`100%20Main%20Street,%20Anytown,%20ST%20ZCcode`

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=100%20Main%20Street,%20Anytown,%20ST%20ZCcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that it was not the program, or a firewall. It was Xcode or the simulator. Quit both, re-opened. Worked fine after. Since it started only after updating to Xcode 6, I figured something had changed. Oh well. Not sure why that would happen. Its working though.